# Anaconda imports tensorflow 2.0.0 even if I've installed tensorflow 1.10.0 in my environment

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I'll summarize my problem as precisely as I can:
I'm using a Windows PC.
I'm using anaconda prompt.
I've created a conda environment with the following command:
`conda create -n ulcm_no_gpu python=3.6 tensorflow=1.10 scipy` (where 'ulcm_no_gpu' is the name of my environment)
and I've activated it with `conda activate ulcm_no_gpu`.
When I run the command `conda list` I obtain the following:

```
(ulcm_no_gpu) C:\Users\Willi\Desktop\GitHub\ulcm>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\Willi\Anaconda3\envs\ulcm_no_gpu:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.2.0                     eigen
absl-py                   0.9.0                    py36_0
astor                     0.8.0                    py36_0
attrs                     19.3.0                     py_0
backcall                  0.2.0                      py_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    3.1.5                      py_0
ca-certificates           2020.1.1                      0
certifi                   2020.4.5.2               py36_0
colorama                  0.4.3                      py_0
decorator                 4.4.2                      py_0
defusedxml                0.6.0                      py_0
entrypoints               0.3                      py36_0
gast                      0.3.3                      py_0
grpcio                    1.27.2           py36h351948d_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
importlib-metadata        1.6.1                    py36_0
importlib_metadata        1.6.1                         0
intel-openmp              2020.1                      216
ipykernel                 5.3.0            py36h5ca1d4c_0
ipython                   7.15.0                   py36_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py36_0
jedi                      0.17.0                   py36_0
jinja2                    2.11.2                     py_0
jsonschema                3.2.0                    py36_0
jupyter_client            6.1.3                      py_0
jupyter_core              4.6.3                    py36_0
libprotobuf               3.11.4               h7bd577a_0
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2
markdown                  3.1.1                    py36_0
markupsafe                1.1.1            py36he774522_0
mistune                   0.8.4            py36he774522_0
mkl                       2020.1                      216
mkl-service               2.3.0            py36hb782905_0
mkl_fft                   1.0.15           py36h14836fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py36h47e9c7a_0
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1
nbconvert                 5.6.1                    py36_0
nbformat                  5.0.7                      py_0
notebook                  6.0.3                    py36_0
numpy                     1.18.1           py36h93ca92e_0
numpy-base                1.18.1           py36hc3f5095_1
openssl                   1.1.1g               he774522_0
packaging                 20.4                       py_0
pandoc                    2.2.3.2                       0
pandocfilters             1.4.2                    py36_1
parso                     0.7.0                      py_0
pickleshare               0.7.5                    py36_0
pip                       20.0.2                   py36_3
prometheus_client         0.8.0                      py_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.5                      py_0
protobuf                  3.11.4           py36h33f27b4_0
pygments                  2.6.1                      py_0
pyparsing                 2.4.7                      py_0
pyrsistent                0.16.0           py36he774522_0
python                    3.6.10               h9f7ef89_2
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0
pywin32                   227              py36he774522_1
pywinpty                  0.5.7                    py36_0
pyzmq                     18.1.1           py36ha925a31_0
scipy                     1.4.1            py36h9439919_0
send2trash                1.5.0                    py36_0
setuptools                47.1.1                   py36_0
six                       1.15.0                     py_0
sqlite                    3.31.1               h2a8f88b_1
tensorboard               1.10.0           py36he025d50_0
tensorflow                1.10.0          eigen_py36h849fbd8_0
tensorflow-base           1.10.0          eigen_py36h45df0d8_0
termcolor                 1.1.0                    py36_1
terminado                 0.8.3                    py36_0
testpath                  0.4.4                      py_0
tornado                   6.0.4            py36he774522_1
traitlets                 4.3.3                    py36_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.16.27012          hf0eaf9b_2
wcwidth                   0.2.4                      py_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py36_1
werkzeug                  1.0.1                      py_0
wheel                     0.34.2                   py36_0
wincertstore              0.2              py36h7fe50ca_0
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
zeromq                    4.3.1                h33f27b4_3
zipp                      3.1.0                      py_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

As we can see from the output above, tensorflow 1.10 has been installed.
Afterwards I run a script as follows:
`python train1d_1d.py`.
This script contains, at the beginning, the following lines I've written for debugging purposes:

```
import sys
print('executable + path:')
print(sys.executable)
print(sys.path)
import tensorflow as tf
print("tf version: {}".format(tf.__version__))
```

and it outputs:

```
executable + path:
C:\Users\Willi\Anaconda3\envs\ulcm_no_gpu\python.exe
['C:\\Users\\Willi\\Desktop\\GitHub\\ulcm', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\win32', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Willi\\Anaconda3\\envs\\ulcm_no_gpu\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
tf version: 2.0.0
```

So I'm wondering why python loads tensorflow 2.0.0 instead of tensorflow 1.10.0.
Do you know what could be the reason?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I scroll down in the result of `conda list` it states that the version of tensorflow is 1.10.0. Are you sure you don't have the correct version of tf in your new environment? Try running `print(tf.__version__)` in a script in this environment to see what version is installed.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the comment. I've just edited the question, because part of what I wrote was inside the code block (so it was probably difficult to see it).   
I did exactly what you suggested me to do, and it outputs: tf version: 2.0.0

Comment: Did you activate your newly created environment before running `python train1d_1d.py`? You'll have to do this every time again. 
I replicated your workflow, created a new environment with tf 1.10, and got no problems whatsoever by activating the env, then navigating to the folder with the script and running it. Also, are you using the command prompt?

Comment: I did activate it, and I'm using anaconda prompt :)   I agree it's strange it is not working. I'm now going to try with other prompts, and I'll let you know.

Comment: I tried to run the script with the basic command prompt of Windows and the problem persists.

Comment: Then this problem exceeds my knowledge as well. The last thing I could recommend is deactivating the env, and creating a new one from scratch (if that is possible). I hope someone else is able to help you better than I could ;)

Comment: thank you anyways Tim :) I already tried out that solution with no luck unfortunately!

Comment: Try to add `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` as well as `print(sys.path)` to the top of your test script. This gives you the python executable that is used to execute your script (should be the one from the env) as well as the paths used to search for imports (should also only point towards paths in your env). Report the results in your question :)

Comment: Thank you FlyingTeller, I've added those lines in the question, and the only path that does not refer to my environment is  'C:\\Users\\Willi\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages', though I don't think it is problematic, what do you think?